# Why Does the Format "_____ Is" When Asking a Question Sound Correct in Some Situations, but Not in Others

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

For context, I am an Assistant Language Teacher for ESL. Part of my job is offering a native speaker's perspective, the main teachers are not native speakers, and I was asked about this. To the other teachers, this structure is always acceptable, but I am not sure about this.

I realized that in some situations, "____ is" sounds like a perfectly fine answer, but in other cases it doesn't. I want to be able to explain to the other teachers and my students why that is, or what the rule is.

For example:

-Who is going to the game tonight?
-She is.

This sounds fine to me.

-What is the most popular sport in America?
-Football is.

This seems okay enough to me.

-What is the name of this book?
-Catcher in the Rye is.

This, to me, sounds off. I'm assuming that other native speakers feel the same way, but I can't seem to figure out the rule. Also, is this actually grammatically correct, but it just feels off?

I should add too that the previous native speakers in my position had told the main teachers that "____ is" is acceptable, and the main teachers are under the impression that they said it is okay in all contexts. So, if I'm going to say that it only works some of the time, I need to explain why.

Comment: It is off, probably because _Catcher in the Rye_ is a proper name, Note that the _is_ is optional in the other ones (though in the first _She_ would have to become _Her_ because it's not a subject before a verb). Note that it's not so bad in the past tense, where there's a reason for it: _What was the previous name of the book? "Shortstop in the Wheat" (was)_.

Comment: ... It's also acceptable when the weighty subject is emphasised. "I don't think there's a single novel about city life in post-war America." / " '_Catcher in the Rye_' is!" // '[I]s this actually grammatically correct, but it just feels off?' doesn't acknowledge Orwell's Sixth Law. Up to a point, idiomaticity trumps rules of standard grammar (certainly, the concept that 'grammatical' = 'acceptable' is unsound).

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I'm going to say that it only works some of the time. I'm pretty good at explaining / researching things, and I'm far from a complete answer here. You certainly **can't** omit the correct form of _be_ after pronouns _I, he, she, it, we_ and _they_. In fact, standard informal/colloquial answers to "Who is going to the game tonight?" include "Me", "Us" and "Them". As stated in answers here (and other comments), heavy subjects resist the addition of _be_.  But I believe the actual question may well have an effect also. Certainly copular and main verb examples should ...

Comment: be considered separately, as @Gustavson points out. However, I'd say that there are far trickier differences to be discovered. // In answer to the question "Is anyone else coming to the lecture on Thursday?', "Ann Smith is" is perfectly acceptable provided Ann Smith is known to the group. But if the secretary has to look the matter up in his predecessor's notes, and finds that an unknown _Ann Smith_ has signed up, "Ann Smith" is far more likely.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a native speaker, but I will give you my view.

In copulative sentences, that is, in sentences where the main verb is "be", subject and subject complement (of a nominal nature) are usually interchangeable:

1.a. Mary is my best friend.

1.b. My best friend is Mary.

In your first sentence, the main verb is "go", so there is no doubt that "she" is the subject and there will be no problem placing it before the auxiliary in a short answer:

- Who is going to the game tonight?
- Mary (is).

Your second and third sentences are copulative and have "be" as the main verb. "what" and "who" may then ask for the subject or for the subject complement. If the information requested is the subject, then the subject + auxiliary answer will sound fine, but if the information requested is the subject complement, it will sound odd.

Of these two pairs of sentences, we can easily tell that the one that sounds natural is that which introduces new information by means of the subject complement:

2.a. Football is the most popular sport in America.

2.b. The most popular sport in America is football.

3.a. The name of this book is *The Catcher in the Rye*.

3.b. *The Catcher in the Rye* is the name of this book.

2.a. and 2.b. are equally natural. Instead, 3.a. sounds more natural than 3.b., and that is because "the name of this book" is a better candidate for subject than "The Catcher in the Rye". Then, when we ask:

- What is the name of this book?

"what" is asking for the subject complement. A more natural reply will then be:

- It (The name of this book)'s *The Catcher in the Rye*.

I’ve come up with some sort of rule to identify whether the *wh*-word asks for the subject or for the subject complement, which consists of **checking the position the reply to "what”, “who” or “which” will occupy in the answer to the question**. Perhaps, as Cascabel said, this belongs on ELL, but since the question has been posed on ELU and has not been migrated (at least, not for the time being), I’d appreciate your comments:

Q2: What is the most popular sport in America?

A2: Football is the most popular sport in America.

“what” may be considered to be in subject position, because it can be replaced with “football” in that front position in the answer. This accounts for the correctness of the short answer “Football is,” and also for the order of the words if the question is embedded:

Embedded Q2: He wants to know what is the most popular sport in America.
(what: subject / is: verb / the most popular sport in America: subject complement)

Alternatively, we can consider that "what" (and "football") is in subject complement position:

Q2': What is the most popular sport in America?

A2': The most popular sport in America is football.

In this case, the embedded question will be different:

Embedded Q2': He wants to know what the most popular sport in America is.
(what: subject complement / the most popular sport in America: subject complement / is: verb)

Let’s see what happens with the other question:

Q3: What is the name of this book?

A3: (It’s) *The Catcher in the Rye*.

In this case, “what” is in subject complement position, and that accounts for the awkwardness of the answer “*The Catcher in the Rye* is.” To further prove this point, we can check what happens when the question is embedded:

Embedded Q3: He wants to know what the name of this book is. (I don't think *He wants to know what is the name of this book* is a good reported question.) (Therefore: what: subject complement / the name of this book: subject / is: verb)

(I admit that other indirect questions would sound more natural, like “He wants to know the name/title of this book” or “He wants to know what this book is called” where, again, “this book” is subject and “what” asks for the subject complement.)

Comment: @Cascabel Sorry but I don't get your point.

Comment: I think this still doesn't allow for clarity on what is considered "a good candidate for subject". That is still left undefined in your answer as much as the question.

Comment: @katatahito I've edited my answer in an attempt to make myself clearer.

Answer (score 2):

## Word proximity habit

Sometimes correct grammar sounds wrong because of our habits. Word proximity is one of the greater factors in forming our habits. I like to call this habit "auto-preference".

*(Maybe its from bad habits, maybe unsophisticated habits, or maybe it is just a less common usage we've encountered.)*

In the examples you gave, all correct and IMHO preferred, the responses you liked each had one word before "is". The response you didn't like had five words before "is". This goes against our habit if having very few words before "is".

Good examples of "strange sounding" use is with possessive pronouns and matching number with the verb.

**Answering the phone to *"Is Susan there?"***

*What we often expect:*

> This is *her*.

*More proper:*

> This is *she*.

...Technically both are correct, but the second one sounds strange because we are accustomed to using object pronouns immediately after the verb. In this case, the first is correct because it treats "her" as an object in the predicate. The second is correct because we use the subject form for a predicate nominative. Either may be used.

**Consider object pronouns**

*What we often expect:*

> The boss called Mitchell and *I*.

*Correct:*

> The boss called Mitchell and *me*.

The issue here is that our "auto-preference" likes to use object pronouns just after verbs, not later in a multi-noun object.

**Consider matching the verb with a singular noun having a plural noun decribing it...**

*What we might expect:*

> Jonathan of the Kansas City Royals *eat* popcorn.

*Correct:*

> Jonathan of the Kansas City Royals *eat**s*** popcorn.

...That one may seem strange to some of us because, most of the time, the subject of the verb comes before it, so our "auto-preference" tries to match the verb with the word before it rather than with the actual subject of the verb. While this may not seem strange to everyone, make it longer and more complex and it will seem strange to more people.

Try this from the thread, which even seemed strange to me. It is correct because the verb and subject must match...

*What our habits might wrongly expect:*

> anything that works against our *habits seem* strange.

*Correct:*

> *anything* that works against our habits *seems* strange.

...Again, having this habitual preference because of "proximity". Our "auto-preference" wants patterns among words right next to each other.

---

***Further consideration***

*On a teaching note, this could be an argument for why memorizing literature or repeatedly practicing correct phrases could prove useful in learning English, native or ESL.*

Comment: So what is your conclusion/suggestion to sort of "codify" this type of preference? In the examples you give there are ""right"" answers, is there one that you see in this case?

Comment: All of his examples are correct. I wouldn't change the third one. Most people wouldn't change it because we naturally prefer lower word count in conversive English, as are his examples.

Comment: as a counter example, If the question is "What is the name of the girl with the long hair?", giving the answer of "Jessica is", also doesn't sound natural even though "Jessica" is a much lower word count.

Comment: All true, I agree. But "word count" was not what I said made it sound strange. My answer to the question was "habit", mainly "proximity". One word answers are our habit, either bad or lazy. It is acceptable in conversation, but "Jessica is" would be correct, just not frequent enough use to form an "auto-preference" habit.

Comment: True, so this may be a situation where a rule isn't able to be divined for all cases, except from experience. And it would also depend on if the speaker just cares about being ""correct"" or sounding ""natural""

Comment: Absolutely! Language is an art and its preference all the more subjective. My answer simply tries to provide some kind of framework to explain the OP "WHY" question about why this kind of "sounds strange" thing happens. It's called "habit", anything that works against our habits seems strange. A more objective rule here would be "proximity", we especially form these habits of preference with words that are closer to each other.

Comment: I'd certainly say that "What boat is in the lead?" ...  "_Ariel_ is" is more likely than the isoformal "What boat is in the lead?" ...  "_Henri Lloyd – 50 Years of Pioneering Spirit_ is".

Comment: But I must add:  << "Is Susan there?" ... "This is her." // More proper: "This is she." >> Proper what? Proper Charlie? I doubt whether _anyone_ would use the nominative here nowadays, even in writing. The 'use the nominative after a copular verb' rule was actually not the original one, if my memory (of treatments, not the actual practice!) serves me right. Who defines 'proper'? G. Pullum has said "If there's a knock at the door, and they answer 'Who is it?' with 'It is I,' don't let them in. It's nobody you want to know."

Comment: "This is she." is also proper because of the use of the Predicate Nominative, so we don't use the oblique.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just because, in the response, "Catcher in the Rye" refers to the title of an entity, not the entity itself? That's why you can say:

> —Which book is left out of the list?
>
> —Catcher in the Rye is.

Here, "Catcher in the Rye" refers to the book as an entity, not to its title.

You could say:

> —What's your favorite book?
>
> —Catcher in the Rye is.

This somewhat implies that the book is known. "Catcher in the Rye" refers to the book, not the title. If the responder assumes that the asker hasn't heard of the book, the response would probably be just "Catcher in the Rye." This would be akin to saying "It's called Catcher in the Rye."